# Qt qreal calculates wrong

Tags: c++, qt

I want to edit the opacity for a `QGraphicsItem` with a `QSpinBox`.
The `QSpinBox` gives me the value **57** which I use to set the opacity of the item.
Then I get the changed opacity back from the item and want to fill the `QSpinBox`. But setting the value of the box results in a mistake.

```
qDebug() << (int)(qreal)(0.57 * 100.0);
```

outputs **56**

Is this a known bug?
Is there a workaround?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integers that fit in the mantissa have exact representation in floating point, thus `static_cast<qreal>(100.0) == 100` always holds and is represented as `100*2^0`.

Rationals with denominators of the form `2^-n` also have exact representation in floating point as long as the numerator fits in the mantissa, thus e.g. `static_cast<qreal>(0.25*4) == 1` holds as long as your compiler doesn't use a brain-dead decimal-to-floating-point conversion function. When most compilers parse the code, they convert both `0.25` and `4` to a floating point representation, and then perform the multiplication to obtain the value of the constant expression.

But `static_cast<qreal>(0.57)` has no representation as `m*2^-n`, with sufficiently small integer `m,n`, and is necessarily represented inexactly. It can be represented as a bit less or more than `0.57`.  Thus when you multiply it by `100`, it can be slightly less than `57` - in your case.

The simplest fix is to avoid the roundtrip: store the opacity everywhere as an integer, and only convert from integer to floating point when changing the value. In other words, only ever use the `setOpacity()` method, and never use the `opacity()` method. Store the integer-valued opacity using the item's data attribute:

```
void setOpacity(QGraphicsItem * item, int opacity) {
  item->setData(kOpacity, opacity);
  item->setOpacity(opacity / 100.0);
}

void getOpacity(QGraphicsItem * item) {
  auto data = item->data(kOpacity);
  if (! data.isNull())
    return data.toInt();
  int opacity = round(item->opacity() * 100.0);
  setOpacity(item, opacity);
  return opacity;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the best way and because I have subclasse QGraphicsItem I fixed this a bit easier.

inline int opacity() {return m_opacity;}
inline void setOpacity(int opacity) {m_opacity = opacity; QGraphicsItem::setOpacity((qreal)m_opacity / 100);}

Answer (score 6):

#### Reason

Do not rely on the precision of the floating point numbers due to the inaccuracy of its calculation. You can read more info on this issue [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/) or [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

#### Demonstration

If you set the higher precision for the output using the [`qSetRealNumberPrecision`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#setRealNumberPrecision), you'll see the actual root of the problem – the result of `0.57 * 100.0` is not exact *57* but something like *56.999999999999992895*:

```
qDebug() << qSetRealNumberPrecision(20) << 0.57 * 100.0;
```

#### Solution

So it's better to simply [round](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qRound) your number to the nearest integer instead of casting to `int` *which simply omits the fraction number*:

```
qDebug() << qRound(0.57 * 100.0);
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a temporary solution but I am not happy with that.

```
qDebug() << "qreal" << (int)(qreal)(0.57 * 100.0);
qDebug() << "double" << (int)(double)(0.57 * 100.0);
qDebug() << "float" << (int)(float)(0.57 * 100.0);
```

Output:
qreal 56,
double 56,
float 57

Comment: This is only a solution if you limit yourself to the value of `57`. Try it with other values! It's not as if it's hard to iterate from 0 to 100 to verify your claim.